# How to exclude first word in Pandas header?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm importing text files to Pandas data frames. Number of columns can vary and also the names varies.

However, the header line always starts with `~A` and read_csv interprets this a s the name of the first column, subsequently all the column names are shifted on step to the right.

Earlier I used `np.genfromtxt()` with the argument `deletechars = 'A__'` but I haven't find any equivalent function for pandas. Is there a way to exclude the name when reading or, as an second option, delete the first name but keep the columns intact?

I'm reading file like this:

```
in_file = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=header_row,delim_whitespace=True)
```

Now I got this (just as the text file looks):

```
             ~A     DEPTH    TIME   TX1   TX2  TX3  OUT6
11705  2.94  10525.38  126.14  169.71  353.86   4.59   NaN
11706  2.93  10525.38  NaN  168.29  368.00   4.75   NaN
11707  2.92  10525.38  126.14  166.71  369.86   4.93   NaN
```

but I want' to get this:

```
       DEPTH    TIME   TX1   TX2  TX3   OUT6
11705  2.94  10525.38  126.14  169.71  353.86   4.59
11706  2.93  10525.38  NaN  168.29  368.00   4.75
11707  2.92  10525.38  126.14  166.71  369.86   4.93
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just post-process?

```
df = ...
df_modified = df[df.columns[:-1]]
df_modified.columns = df.columns[1:]
```

Comment: Yes, probably the way to go.

Comment: Can you kindly explain what each of the two lines is doing?

Answer (score 2):

How about if you read the file twice?  First, use `pd.read_csv()` but skip your header row.  Second, use `open.readline()` to parse the header and drop the first item. This can then be assigned to your dataframe.

```
in_file = pd.read_csv(file_name, delim_whitespace=True, header = None, skiprows = [0])
with open(file_name,'rt') as h:
    hdrs = h.readline().rstrip('\n').split(',')
in_file.columns = hdrs[1:]
```

Comment: That's an innovative solution!

Answer (score 0):

Choose which columns to import

```
in_file = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=header_row,
             delim_whitespace=True,
             usecols=['DEPTH','TIME','TX1','TX2','TX3','OUT6')
```

Comment: Unfortunately the columns vary. Also, the header and the columns would still not fit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if the number of columns vary
and you want to remove the first column (who's name varies)
AND you do not want too do this in a Post-cv_read phase...
then 
.... (Drum Roll)

import pandas as pd

```
#Tim.csv is
#1,2,3
#2,3,4
#3,4,5
headers=['BADCOL','Happy','Sad']
data = pd.read_csv('tim.csv').iloc[:,1:]
```

Data will now look like

```
    b   c
    2   3
    3   4
    4   5
```

Not sure if this counts as Post-CSV processing or not...